# R: Variable number of output list items using Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

With renderUI in server.R, I'm trying to allow for a variable number of list items.  This is a non-working attempt.

```
output$myList <- renderUI({
  tagList(
    tags$ul(
      for(i in 1:nrow(df) {
        tags$li(df$myCol[i])
      }
    )
  )
})
```

In this example, the number of list items would depend on the number of rows in df.  I could just print the table, but I want the formatting of the list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` return nothing so you have 2 variant

1) use lapply

2) Create list and return it

## examples

1)

```
df=data.frame(myCol=1:10)

  tags$ul(
    lapply( 1:nrow(df),function(i){
      tags$li(df$myCol[i])
    }
    ))
```

2)

```
  tags$ul({
    list_1=list()
    for(i in 1:nrow(df) ){
      list_1[[i]]= tags$li(df$myCol[i])
    }
    list_1}
    )
```